# Is it possible to change the value of a string added in res/strings.xml on Android at run time/ or by code?

Tags: android

I know we can use resource strings to store values, but is it possible to change those values at run time?

For example, I added two new resource elements username and password, and I want to change these values at run time. Or is there an alternate way to store values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change value of R.string programically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674925/change-value-of-r-string-programically)

Answer (score 19):

String resources are absolutely static defined; you can't change their values. Use `SharedPreference` which is to store your data, and you can change, update or do whatever to suit your needs.

Here is a sample for using `SharedPreference`: *[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)*

Answer (score 2):

`strings.xml` are for constant strings only. Their values can change automatically when the phone language changes provided that you have created several `strings.xml` files such as `strings-us.xml, strings-fr.xml`.

You can store username & password values in Preferences. They will be stored permanently with your application.