# Storing strings in string.xml

Tags: android, string

I have two string that store in string.xml like this

```
<string name="Domain">http://discovervideo.com/station/index.guid=</string>
<string name="Guid">default</string>
```

and two EditText t1 , t2 while

```
t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server1);
t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signage1);
```

I want when user input this two string it update to string.xml where I used them in another activity like

```
String Domain = getResources().getString(R.string.Domain);
String GUID = getResources().getString(R.string.Guid);
```

It is possible to do that?

Comment: thanks @Fllo just question

Comment: No. strings.xml can't be edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible as far as I know (another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258650/is-it-possible-to-change-value-of-string-added-in-res-strings-xml-in-android-at) about it). Consider using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for that purpose.

Comment: Santi, instead of posting an answer (beside that maybe should be a comment) with a dup question, it might be better to flag this question as a duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: You're right. Excuse me!

Answer (score 1):

For this, you should probably used SharedPreferences.

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// To save a string...
prefs.edit().putString(KEY_WHATEVER, "Your value").commit();

// To load that string
prefs.getString(KEY_WHATEVER, "A default value");
```

Then you just need to create the FILE_NAME and KEY_WHATEVER variables (and probably give them better names). They are just used so that SharedPreferences knows what to load.

Comment: good example thanks very much :D