# Android - How to inject a values/strings.xml in runtime

Tags: android

Consider that I have an Rest API that let me fetch a `strings.xml` file.
Once downloaded is it posible set as the default `values/strings.xml` file of the app?

Comment: Why would you do that. What kind of resources would be shown to user between app start and resource loaded?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258650/is-it-possible-to-change-the-value-of-a-string-added-in-res-strings-xml-on-andro/8258712) , it looks like you can not do it from the answer

Answer (score 4):

String resources are static defined and can not be changed at runtime.

However, you could use the [Restring](https://github.com/B3nedikt/restring) library to set and load strings at runtime by adding the dependencies:

```
// Replace bundled strings dynamically
implementation 'dev.b3nedikt.restring:restring:4.0.3'

// Intercept view inflation
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'

// Allows to update the text of views at runtime without recreating the activity
implementation 'dev.b3nedikt.reword:reword:1.1.0'
```

Initialising it in your Application class:

```
Restring.init(this,
        new RestringConfig.Builder()
                .stringsLoader(new SampleStringsLoader())
                .loadAsync(false) // If string loader should load strings asynchronously, default true
                .build()
        );

ViewPump.init(ViewPump.builder()
        .addInterceptor(RewordInterceptor.INSTANCE)
        .build());
```

Then it should be injected into context:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(ViewPumpContextWrapper.wrap(Restring.wrapContext(newBase)));
}

@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    return Restring.wrapContext(getBaseContext()).getResources();
}
```

And you can load more strings at any time:

```
// e.g. locale=Locale.EN newStrings=map of (key-value)s
Restring.setStrings(locale, newStrings);
```

And apply updated resources without restarting the app:

```
// The layout containing the views you want to localise
final View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
Reword.reword(rootView);
```

More details: https://github.com/B3nedikt/restring